# Having issues with images overlapping using CSS

Tags: css, image-scaling, responsive-images

Initially, I had this formatted the way that I wanted. After adding and removing code over the last few hours, I'm unsure of what revision that I made that prevents me from separating the individual images. They're supposed to be side-by-side with about 5em in between.

HTML —

```
<div class="techStackContainer02">
    <div class="techImg">
       <img class="techImg" src="client image.svg" alt="client">
       <img class="techImg" src="server image.svg" alt="server">
       <img class="techImg" src="database.svg" alt="database">
    </div>
```

CSS —

```
.techStackContainer02 {
    display: grid;
    gap: 5em;
    height: 15vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
}

.techImg {
    height: 180px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%;
}
```

[Preview of Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKyph.png)

I've tried using a few resources online but majority of them just discuss positioning attributes (sticky, absolute, fixed, etc.). Using the *relative* position for my parent container and *absolute* for my images has them at least placed in a singular row. Everything is sized properly minus the aforementioned overlapping issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify **position: absolute;** you have to specify the exact position you want for each element.

In this case, they are naturaly overlapping because their positions are determined by the values of **top, right, bottom, and left**. since you didn't specify any they are in the exact same position.

You can just remove your **position: absolute** in your **.techImg** css class and they will not overlap anymore. Maybe you have to adjust you width to get every images on the same lines.

Here is an example with random images :

```css
.techStackContainer02 {
    display: grid;
    gap: 5em;
    height: 15vh;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}

.techImg {
    height: 180px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="techStackContainer02">
    <div class="techImg"> <!-- problem here -->
       <img class="techImg" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="client">
       <img class="techImg" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="server">
       <img class="techImg" src="https://picsum.photos/50" alt="database">
    </div>
```

EDIT : i juste realize the code you posted got 1 additional div with the techImg class aswell. Maybe you have to use another class name if you don't want to have strange effects.

Comment: This worked exactly as stated. Thank you for your prompt response!